# Infura with JWT authentication

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura, authentication

I am using wallet connect  an Open protocol for connecting Wallets to Dapps with web3 modal sdk . the wallet connect requires an infura key. Since the wallet connect is executed on the borwser it exposes the infura key on the front end.  However infura offers a way to send a request with jwt authentication. how do i integrate it with wallet connect?

````
     walletconnect: {
       package: WalletConnectProvider,
       options: {
    
         infuraId: 
                   "f081axxxxxx9891818968bda7e4f6"
                   
       }
      ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to authenticate the user yourself. Provide them the credentials "JWT" to be authorized with infura. Authenticating users is done in the back-end. Because one way or another, you need to store the key you will use to generate each users key. This is why Infura do not handle private key.

You can read about it here;

https://infura.io/docs/ethereum#section/Project-Security/Securing-With-JWTs

https://www.ibm.com/docs/da/order-management?topic=SSGTJF/configuration/t_GeneratingJWTToken.html

options?

1. You change the key every now and then.
2. You sync a node yourself and let your dApp access it freely.
3. You build a centralized back-end and pay for it's upkeep to store a free api key?
4. You don't worry to much about it because you can always switch to metamask anyways.

Comment: clearly explained, I appreciate it.